# function composition proof with identity functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, function-and-relation-composition

I need to prove: $(g \circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$.

Is this okay?:

$(g \circ f) \circ (f^{-1} \circ g^{-1})=g \circ (f \circ f^{-1}) \circ g^{-1}=g\circ id_{A} \circ g^{-1}=g \circ g^{-1}= id_{A}$ .

Comment: On the right side of your "to prove" statement it should be $f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$. Rest is fine.

Comment: right, fixed that. thanks